# Locating the coordinates of an element within a layer in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

I have a PSD which I've opened up in Gimp (because I currently don't have Photoshop) and I am having difficulty with locating any functionality on the Gimp UI that would help determine the positioning and dimensions of a given element in any layer. Is there anything that could provide me with a way of finding the position and dimensions of the individual elements?

Any advice that would help assist would be greatly appreciated... I am not graphic-design orientated, but have some understanding of Gimp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way is just to look at the bottom left corner of your workspace. There you'll find the exact position of your cursor (1). You can even change the dropdown to cm, px, inches, etc. (2) Of course, this isn't very accurate, but it gets the job done fast and dirty.

[image: positioning in Gimp]

---

A second and more accurate way is using the pointer dialog. You can find it under windows > dockable dialogs > pointer

This also gives you the current position of your cursor, but with much more options.

[image: gimp positioning 2]

---

A third and even more accurate way to find a position, width and height is using the measure tool (the one next to the looking glass). Be sure to select 'use info window'.

[image: gimp width-heigth]

---

And if that doesn't do it for you, take a look at [this link](http://registry.gimp.org/node/24455).

Comment: Will that work for elements I've selected from the layers list?

Comment: It just gives you the exact position of your cursor, regardless of layers, elements, etc. So it's not very accurate if you really need pixel perfect positions.

Comment: I've added a few more options that might be more suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can draw a bounding box with the selection tool. Then from the pointer window, you can tell the x, y, w and h of the bounding box. Hope this helps.